# modify an upcoming boolean inside an array in the if statement in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, if-statement, indexing

The first item in the array of objects has it's state as `isNext` `true`. The rest are all `false`. I am using an `if` statement and want to turn the current boolean `false` and the next one `true`. I basically want to only call one image at a time once I hit the submit button. (haven't gotten to the button yet). I know the below function is a mess, but that is basically how I am conceiving of the issue. I am not sure how to use `i` to manipulate both the current and upcoming iteration of the array. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
generateImage() {
 return this.state.images.map((image, i) => {
   if(image[i].isNext === true) {
     image[i].isNext = false
     image[i + 1].isNext = true;
    return  <Image src={image.img} index={i} />
   }
 });
}
```

`this.state`

```
 images: [
          {
          img: 'https://uploads3.wikiart.org/images/wladyslaw-strzeminski/cover-for-a-book-by-julian-przybo-z-ponad-1930.jpg!Large.jpg',
          thought: '',
          isNext: true
        },
        {
          img: 'https://uploads6.wikiart.org/images/pablo-picasso/girl-on-the-ball-1905.jpg!Large.jpg',
          thought: '',
          isNext: false
        },
        {
          img: 'https://uploads8.wikiart.org/images/salvador-dali/et-post-buccellam-introivit-in-eum-satanas-psalms-40-10-1964.jpg',
          thought: '',
          isNext: false
        },
      ]
```

Comment: So what problem are you having? And why this json structure?

Comment: I am new to React and am trying to use ``` this.state``` structure that I've seen elsewhere. When ```generateImage()``` runs I want the current ```image.isNext``` to now equal ```false``` and the next image in the array of objects to be ```true```. ```image[i].isNext``` returns undefined.

Comment: Why do you have TWO returns in the first segment of code? Also, please console.log(image) just inside the map loop and see what you get.

Comment: It doesn't work without the two returns. Here is what I get from the ```console.log ```

```{img: "https://uploads3.wikiart.org/images/wladyslaw-strz…-book-by-julian-przybo-z-ponad-1930.jpg!Large.jpg", thought: "", isNext: true}```

Comment: I am assuming you have more than 3 entries in images? How do you deal when you come to the end of images?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATED:

https://codesandbox.io/s/blazing-haze-u5fvz?file=/src/ClassExample.js

I have provided two examples. One using hooks and one using classes.

Take a peek and let me know.

```
  updateThought(thought) {
    //Function that findIndex uses to search for isNext/current image
    const isNext = image => image.isNext === true;
    //state should be immutable. Using lodash library for deep clone.
    let tempImages = cloneDeep(this.state.images);
    const currentIndex = tempImages.findIndex(isNext);

    tempImages[currentIndex].isNext = false;
    tempImages[currentIndex].thought = thought;
    //set the next picture to true, check to makesure we didn't go to far
    if (currentIndex + 1 < tempImages.length) {
      tempImages[currentIndex + 1].isNext = true;
    } else {
      //Go back to the first image, or you can display a done message
      tempImages[0].isNext = true;
    }
    this.setState({
      images: tempImages
    });
  }
```

Comment: Absolutely, I tend to be tentative with describing the whole project in my initial posting of the problem but I agree it would help give better context to my problem due to length concerns. I am eventually trying to get the images from the database and will generate multiple inputs along with each image. The user can then put in their 'thoughts' about the painting limited by the input count, which would also save to a database. Thank you so much for helping out a newbie. I'll take some time dissecting the code you have written.

Comment: Every tutorial seems to use ```state``` for everything. I am curious why you didn't use the images array inside of a state?

Comment: I just left it as an array as I was not sure of your big picture.Now that I know more, I will update the example.

Comment: its amazing, again, I look forward to dissecting it. I really appreciate it.